# How do I display a different label text from the value as done with a dropdown list in MVC 5 EF 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Currently my oracle table has values Y/N for Enable and Disable. When editing the row the dropdownlist shows, Enable and Disable.

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FLAG, htmlAttributes: new { @class ="control-  label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.DropDownList("FLAG", new List<SelectListItem>{new SelectListItem{Text ="Enable",Value="Y",Selected=true},
new SelectListItem{Text ="Disable",Value="N"}})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FLAG, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div></div>
```

My Issue:

in the index page where the records are shown, the Value of the column "Y" shows. I would like to show Enabled and disabled in the index page instead of the value "Y" or the value "N". is there an html helper like the dropdownlist but a label that shows a customized text based on value as I did with the SelectListItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom helper for that purpose. You can add it inside the view using the following method:

```
// You can use Char type instead
@helper replaceValue(String val){ 
    if(val.ToLower().Equals("y"){
         <span style="color:green"> Enabled</span>
    }
    else if(val.ToLower().Equals("n"){
         <span style="color:red"> Disabled</span>
    }
    else{
         <span> N/A</span>
    }
}
```

Or you may define as an extension method for example

```
public static class Extensions{
    public static MvcHtmlString replaceVal(this HtmlHelper html, [And your parameters]){
        ... // You logic here
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I posted my code for the custom helper class.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code for custom expression:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  @Html.LabelCustom(model => model.FMLA_FLAG) </div>


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace SurveyMaster.CustomHelpers
    {
        public static class CustomHTMLHelpers
        {
            public static MvcHtmlString LabelCustom<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
            {
                string displayValue = "";

                string Value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData).Model.ToString();
                if (Value == "Y")
                    displayValue = "Enabled";
                else if(Value == "N")
                    displayValue = "Disabled";
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", Value, displayValue));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also use the `TagBuilder` type to generate HTML in a more efficient way.

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work for a label. I got it to work for a textbox as I was able to set the property value, but I wasn't sure what to do for  a label.